# Pivot Table Changing Cell Colors

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am hoping someone can help me figure out a really annoying aesthetic feature of pivot tables in Excel.

Here is what my current "analysis" screen looks like without the pivot tables:
[image] 
However, I have placed pivot tables in the black boxes and have a macro to auto update them after I import more data. That is below:

```
Sub UpdatePivots()
    ' This sub is intended to update all pivot charts in the by switching to the appropriate
    ' worksheet, locating the appropriate pivot table, and updating them.

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim pvtItem As PivotItem

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets '<~~ Loop all worksheets in workbook
        For Each PT In ws.PivotTables        '<~~ Loop all pivot tables in worksheet
            PT.PivotCache.Refresh
        Next PT
    Next ws
End Sub
```

However, the imported data changes. Sometimes it is very small, sometimes it is very large, and so I end up with my pivot tables looking like this:
[image]

How is it possible for me to either write code, or change settings, so those ugly white rows don't appear? I would like for the gray to remain if there are no pivot rows. I have tried checking in Pivot Table formatting settings but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: You can use the `.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` property to figure out how many rows your pivot table uses and then format the other cells appropriately.

Comment: Hi @urdearboy, thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it cannot, as I have other things in my workbook such as query tables that would be affected by that. Further, that is not relevant to my question.

Comment: @JerryM. understood. Didn't think about that. Was just a suggestion that popped into my head when first reading your question :)

Comment: @urdearboy not a problem! I appreciate the suggestion, just don't think it is applicable here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard last row identifier and then color your interior cells below. You will need to pick a max row number (here it always color form last row down to 100, so change 100 if needed). You will also need to set the columns since you have a black border.

Last, you will just need to add the color code. I added a bit of code below to extract the color code if you don't know what it already.

This solution will work for the left pivot. You will need to duplicate the two lines of code I added for the pivot on right.

---

```
Sub UpdatePivots()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable, pvtItem As PivotItem
Dim LRow As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each PT In ws.PivotTables
        PT.PivotCache.Refresh
        LRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(LRow, "D"), ws.Cells(100, "G")).Interior.Color = 11184814
    Next PT
Next ws

End Sub
```

---

If you do not know the color code, you can run the below code to find it!

```
Sub ColorCode()

Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Application.InputBox("Select desired cell to return color code", Type:=8)

If Not Target.Count > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Color Code: " & Target.Interior.Color
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I removed your comments and re-organized just for readability with the solution. There is nothing wrong with how your code was set up

Comment: Very interesting. I will test this in one moment, though it seems promising. I didn't think to calculate the size of the pivot table, that was smart.

Comment: Hello. I cant seem to get this proposed solution to work properly, and I believe that is because I asked a poor question. I have edited my question to reflect this @urdearboy

Comment: Further, I used your code sample to determine the color is 11184814

Comment: Sure. One moment: "VBA Runtime Error 1004 “Object-defined error” on the line 'ws.Range(ws.Cells(LRow, B), ws.Cells(100, F)).Interior.Color = 11184814'

Comment: Take your time. I am working through this as well, trying to debug. Again, I updated my question to better reflect what the worksheet looks like to hopefully have your answer include proper columns / headings so others may find it useful

Comment: Alright, I just did another update. This should work for your pivot table on the left. Since it looks like your pivots will indeed vary in size, you will just need to duplicate the 2 rows I added for the pivot on right.